# How to specify function arguments within mutate_at

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to convert multiple columns of a data.frame from the character class to the factor class while specifying the factor labels.

First I will create a dummy data.frame on which the code should such that others can reproduce the issue as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:1,20,rep=TRUE)),
                 replicate(2,sample(0:2,20,rep=TRUE)))
names(df) <- c("xxx_var1", "xxx_var2", "yyy_var1", "yyy_var2")
```

I have managed to convert the desired columns as follows:

```
df <- df %>%
   mutate_at(vars(starts_with("xxx")), factor)
```

Now I want to specify arguments in the factor() function but I don't know how. If I try the following:

```
df <- df %>%
   mutate_at(vars(starts_with("xxx")), factor(labels = c("no", "yes"))
```

it returns the following error:

> Error in factor(labels = c("no", "yes")) :
> invalid 'labels'; length 2 should be 1 or 0

Is it possible to specify the factor labels for all these columns at once using mutate_at?

Comment: Are you familiar with `map` functions from `purrr` package? Also, can you provide a sample of the data you are using to make the problem reproducible in our machines? You can do that using dput(head(df)) and copying the result from the console.

Comment: It would help to see a representative sample of the data in `df` as plain text _e.g._ the output from `dput(df)`.

Comment: `df %>%
   mutate_at(vars(starts_with("xxx")), factor, labels = c("no", "yes"))`?

Comment: `library(dplyr); df %>% mutate(across(starts_with("xxx"), ~factor(., levels = c("no", "yes"))))`

Comment: @jdobres you solution worked, thanks a lot! Very clean and simple. If you could post your idea as an answer I can accept it as the proper solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide `factor`'s "labels" argument as a named argument to `mutate_at`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("xxx")), factor, labels = c("no", "yes"))
```

However, the `mutate_xxx` functions have been superseded by the use of `mutate` and the new `across` function. As Jon Spring commented, the following is equivalent:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("xxx"), ~factor(., levels = c("no", "yes"))))
```